# Finding correlation between features and target column

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, linear-regression, correlation

I am trying to build a `Regression` model and I am looking for a way to check whether there's any correlation between features and target variables?

This is just my sample `dataset`

```
     Loan_ID    Gender  Married Dependents  Education Self_Employed ApplicantIncome\    

0   LP001002    Male    No         0        Graduate      No            5849    
1   LP001003    Male    Yes        1        Graduate      No            4583    
2   LP001005    Male    Yes        2        Graduate     Yes            3000    
3   LP001006    Male    Yes        0        Not Graduate  No            2583    
4   LP001008    Male    No         3+       Graduate      No            6000    

CoapplicantIncome  LoanAmount   Loan_Amount_Term  Credit_History Area Loan_Status
      0.0               123          360.0            1.0        Urban     Y
      1508.0          128.0          360.0            1.0        Rural     N
      0.0              66.0          360.0            1.0        Urban     Y
      2358.0          120.0          360.0            1.0        Urban     Y
      0.0             141.0          360.0            1.0    SemiUrban     Y
```

I am trying to predict `LoanAmount` column based on the features available above.

I just want to see if there's a correlation between the features and target variable. I tried `LinearRegression`, `GradientBoostingRegressor` and I'm hardly getting a accuracy of around `0.30 - 0.40%`.

Any suggestions on algorithms, params etc that I should use for better prediction?

Comment: Please proofread: your title has nothing to do with your actual question (correlation has a very specific meaning in this context, which is not necessarily related to prediction)...

Comment: First, since this is regression, `0.30 - 0.40` is R-squared value and not accuracy.  Second is it 0.30-0.40 percent or 30-40 percent? Third predicting the loan-amount only based on this information will be difficult task, you will need much more data and more features (Because loan amount not only depends on the bank but also on applicant (how much does he want - which may be very lower or upper than what the bank can give) . However you can predict `'Loan_Status'` (classification task).

Comment: @VivekKumar How can I predict Loan_Status then? Any steps that I should do before proceeding with the classification task apart from using `labelencoder()`?

Comment: First try the same dataset with that you were using with `LinearRegression, GradientBoostingRegressor` and use that with classifiers like `LogisticRegression, GradientBoostingClassifier`.

Comment: @VivekKumar Ok. Do I need to use `pd.get_dummies` for any column before training the model? I was thinking of using `pd.get_dummies` on `area and dependents column`. I also used `minmaxscalar` for feature scaling. Are there any other reprocessing steps that I should do before proceeding?

Comment: I dont think so. Does any of your features have more than two values? Use the same processing that you did to get the data which you passed to the `fit()` of LinearRegression.

Comment: @VivekKumar Only `Area` and `Dependents` column has more vaues. You can check the question. I've updated it.

Comment: Dependent column is a continuous one. So no need to one-hot encode that. You can try one-hot encoding the Area.

Comment: @VivekKumar `Dependent column` has only four values [`0,1,2,3+`] that keep repeating for all rows. So is it still continuous one? I was assuming it's a category label and the values are string not int because it has `3+`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181280/discussion-between-vivek-kumar-and-user2475).

Answer (score 0):

With [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.corr.html) you can easy check linear correlation between the features and target column:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('path_to_file')
df.corr()
```

You should keep in mind, that would be linear correlation.

Answer (score 0):

For continuous variables like `ApplicantIncome` and `CoapplicantIncome`, if you are only interested in finding correlations, then you can use some correlation coefficient. The most common ones are [Pearson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_correlation_coefficient) for linear correlations and [Spearman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spearman%27s_rank_correlation_coefficient) or [Kendall tau](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kendall_rank_correlation_coefficient) for nonlinear correlations.

Regarding implementation, these can be found in Pandas as [pandas.DataFrame.corr()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.corr.html) (I really recommend you working with Pandas if you're not already.)

Regarding categorical to continuous association, there is no such thing as a correlation. You can only measure association.

I have not enough experience working with these, but I know you can use ANOVA or Kruskal-Wallis. Refer to [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/124618/196392) for more information if you like.

(I'd suggest moving this question to Cross Validated.)